# Find a specific key out of few given keys from a hashmap in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have the following hashmap out of which I want to find if it contains a specific key out of the below 4 keys. In Java 7 I can do below. How can I do the same in Java8?

```
Map<String, String> filterParamsMap = new HashMap<>();
filterParamsMap.put("CRN", "1234");

String key;
for (String customReference : filterParamsMap.keySet()) {
    if (customReference.equalsIgnoreCase("CCN") || customReference.equalsIgnoreCase("PRN")
    || customReference.equalsIgnoreCase("PCCN") || customReference.equalsIgnoreCase("CRN")) {

                key = customReference;
    }
```

I tried but I'm able to check just 1 string out of the above 4. Also, it returns boolean whereas my output should be a String.

```
String key = filterParamsMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(r->r.contains("CRN"));
```

I cannot do the below:

```
String key = filterParamsMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(r->r.contains("CRN")||r->r.contains("PRN")||r->r.contains("PCCN")
                ||r->r.contains("CCN"));
```

Comment: Why does you original code use `equalsIgnoreCase` but when you try a Stream approach, you suddenly use `contains`? Are you aware of the differences between these methods? Which match operation do you actually need? A plain `equals` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `anyMatch()` along with `String#matches()`:

```java
String regex = "CRN|PRN|PCCN|CCN"
List<String> matchedResults = filterParamsMap.keySet().stream().filter(key -> key.matches(regex)).map(filterParamsMap::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here are using a regex alternation which contains the 4 possible key values which you want to match.  Note that `String#matches()` implicitly applies the input pattern to the entire string.  More generally, we would use the following regex pattern:

```
^(?:CRN|PRN|PCCN|CCN)$
```

Comment: can't edit your post( good solution but `Stream#anyMatch` returns `boolean`. Instead it should be `Stream#filter`: 
`List<String> matchedResults = filterParamsMap.keySet().stream().filter(key -> key.matches(regex)).map(filterParamsMap::get).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I have edited per your comment.

Comment: Note that the OP used `equalsIgnoreCase`. If plain equality is needed, it is way more efficient to use four `containsKey` checks instead of searching a map of unknown size linearly. Otherwise, you need a case insensitive pattern but keep in mind that each time you’re calling `matches(regex)` on a string, you’re repeating the expensive operation [`Pattern.compile(regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)). If the map might be large, you’re better off compiling it once and reusing it.

Comment: Since JDK 11, you can use `Pattern.compile(regex).asMatchPredicate()` which is only slightly longer than `key -> key.matches(regex)` but won’t repeat the `compile` step for every key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter function and then find the first occurence.

```
String key = filterParamsMap.keySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(r -> {return r.contains("CRN") || r.contains("PRN") || r.contains("PCCN") || r.contains("CCN");})
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

[findFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) returns [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) you can use this object later on to validate further. In my example above I return null object if no object found because get() method will throw NoSuchElementException if there is no object found, but the behavior is up to you maybe you want to catch this exception or not this is for example purposes only.